# iOS app signature verification fails on new release

Tags: ios, flutter, codesign

I had to move my iOS app development project (based on Flutter) to a new computer. Since then any new release of the app that I upload to TestFlight fails to install saying

> This app cannot not be installed because its integrity could not be verified.

I believe I transferred all my keys from the old computer to the new one. I compile my app with

```
flutter build ipa --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=ios/debug
```

The compilation gives no errors. I tried uploading the app with `xcrun altool ...` as well as the Transporter app and also by opening Runner.xcarchive in xcode, nothing worked.

My signing settings has not changed, I rolled back my build settings to a known good version that was working on my old machine.

Unfortunately I'm unable to boot up the old machine anymore, it got stuck in a bootloop when upgrading to Ventura. But I have a backup and can access any file on it.

Using Ventura 13.0.1, Xcode 14.1, Flutter 3.3.9.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact problem; I fixed it by removing the ios folder and running:

```
flutter create .
```

thereafter added all configuration that had been deleted from the ios folder back. It is frustrating, but at least were able to use TestFlight to install the app again.